# Observer for removed items in the cart

Tags: magento, observer-pattern

Is there an observer which can be used to observe events when a product is removed from the cart? I haven't found any.

What I have found is `checkout_cart_update_items_after` which can be used if a product is removed by altering the product count, but not when the user uses the remove button. The only alternative I see in the moment is `checkout_cart_save_after` which is used whenever the cart changes. Of course this needs custom logic which check which product was removed. Not perfect.

So is there a better way to watch out for remove events?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `sales_quote_remove_item` event, dispatched in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::removeItem()`.
The removed item is passed to the observer as an argument.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_remove_item', array('quote_item' => $item));
```

To get the associated product model in an event observer, use `$observer->getQuoteItem()->getProduct()`.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the question of watching for events (whatever they may be), see `Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent()`. Sample debug/logging code:

```
public function dispatchEvent($eventName, $args)
{
    $argsArray = array();

    $logfile = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir().'/var/log/events.log','a');

    if(is_array($args)){
        foreach ($args as $k => $v){
            switch (gettype($v)) {
                case 'object':
                    $v = get_class($v);
                    break;
                case 'array':
                    $v = 'array';
            }
            $argsArray[$k] = $v;
        }
    }

    $log = $eventName.":\r\t";
    foreach($argsArray as $k => $v){
        $log .= $k;
        $log .= "\r\t\t".$v;
    }
    $log .= "\r\r";

    fwrite($logfile,$log);
    fclose($logfile);

    // ...Rest of method...
}
```