# Does magento store the items that are removed from cart?

Tags: magento

Is there a way to see all the items that were added and then later removed from a sales quote?  How would you access them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191951/observer-for-removed-items-in-the-cart

Comment: Not a duplicate. Easy to setup an observer to track cart adds/deletes. I was hoping for a retro active approach. Thats why I was wondering if if the changes were stored anywhere.